# What are all the various ways to define constants imported from components? (in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly advanced in React and Javascript overall, but I cannot find the right words to form my question so I will use examples (Would appreciate for someone to fill in the gaps, who is more eloquent in the field).

So when I do `import { useRef, useState } from "react";` I obviously get the functions defined as constants without having to access the object first React.useRef => useRef

Then there's `const { camera, size, gl: { domElement }} = useThree()`
So how would I be able to access size, which contains width and height (size.width/size.height), without having to access the size object first? I would prefer to just get width returned without defining another `const` first.

Is there a documentation on all of that, that I missed?

Comment: Yes, thank you now I know what to look for and that I was trying to ask about "ES6 Destructuring". Helps me write shorter code! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Realized the solution myself, but I would still be curious about other use cases and the proper documentation.

`const { camera, size: { width, height }, gl: { domElement }} = useThree()`